# Update multiple nodes in a single query, each with different property / value pairs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A similar question was answered by Michael Hunger in early 2013 however I am unable to translate his response to Neo4j/Cypher 3.x.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/qZWhbMtMCTE/r3W7OZfCgAgJ

Each node has at a property with a UUID value.
In some cases the "second" property is a Boolean, in other cases a string.

I want to update some of these nodes, changing or adding a property to each one.

```
(n1 {uuid:"foo1", enabled: true})
(n2 {uuid:"foo2", example: "foo"})
(n3 {uuid:"foo3"})
```

I could of course create a separate MERGE and SET statement for each but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution:

```
MATCH (S {uuid:"foo0"})
MERGE (n2 {uuid:"foo2"})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(S)
    SET n2.example="bar"
MERGE (n3 {uuid:"foo3"})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(S)
    SET n3.enabled=true
```

Comment: What are the `BELONGS_TO` relationships for?

Comment: The specific relationship name "BELONGS_TO" is arbitrary. The purpose of the relationship was to ensure all the nodes of this type, namely those potentially created by MERGE, were attached to the "S" node.

Answer (score 6):

The following simple Cypher query can be used to add/update an arbitrary set of properties for any number of uuids. It will also create the node for a uuid if one does not already exist.

```
UNWIND {data} AS d
MERGE (x {uuid: d.uuid})
SET x += d.props;
```

It expects the `{data}` [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters) to be an array of objects. The following array contains the same sample data as in your question:

```
[
  {uuid: 'foo1', props:{enabled: true}},
  {uuid: 'foo2', props:{example: 'foo'}},
  {uuid: 'foo3', props:{}}
]
```

In each data array element, the `props` object can contain any number of properties, and they will be added/updated accordingly in the node with the given `uuid`.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed--thank you!
I am using PHP which lacks object literals so I needed to tweak the parameter syntax as follows:  

`(object) ['uuid'=>'foo', 'props' => (object) ['enabled' => true]]`  

..essentially create an array and type-cast it to an object.

Comment: How would you do this if you were matching by ID(x)?

Comment: Replace `MERGE (x {uuid: d.uuid})` with `MERGE (x) WHERE ID(x) = d.id`.