# Update properties of many nodes selected by ID

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is a slightly different question from one answered here:

[Update multiple nodes in a single query, each with different property / value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975496/update-multiple-nodes-in-a-single-query-each-with-different-property-value-pa)

The selected answer to that question presented a nifty query to update many nodes by their 'uuid':

```
UNWIND { data } AS d 
MERGE (x {uuid: d.uuid})
SET x += d.props
```

My question is how would you accomplish this if you wanted to select by ID(x)? While most of my nodes do have a uuid property, my relationships do not and I need to update their properties as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming since you have IDs for your relationships, that they don't need to be merged, just need to match to them and update properties?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to process your nodes and relationships separately. Relationships would process similar to this:

```
UNWIND { data } AS d 
MATCH ()-[r]-()
WHERE id(r) = d.id
SET r += d.props
```

Node processing would be similar, just use `MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = d.id`

Comment: This is great, thank you. I didn't know doing it this way would update the parameters in the correct order.